# C99: compiler optimizations when accessing global variables and aliased memory pointers

Tags: c, performance, global-variables, c99, restrict

I'm writing C code for an embedded system. In this system, there are memory mapped registers at some fixed address in the memory map, and of course some RAM where my data segment / heap is.

I'm finding problems generating optimal code when my code is intermixing accesses to global variables in the data segment and accesses to hardware registers. This is a simplified snippet:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t * const restrict HWREGS = 0x20000;

struct {
    uint32_t a, b;
} Context;

void example(void) {
    Context.a = 123;
    HWREGS[0x1234] = 5;
    Context.b = Context.a;
}
```

This is the code generated on x86 (see also on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9K99q15vz)):

```
example:
        mov     DWORD PTR Context[rip], 123
        mov     DWORD PTR ds:149712, 5
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR Context[rip]
        mov     DWORD PTR Context[rip+4], eax
        ret
```

As you can see, after having written the hardware register, `Context.a` is reloaded from RAM before being stored into `Context.b`. This doesn't make sense because `Context` is at a different memory address than `HWREGS`. In other words, the memory pointed by `HWREGS` and the memory pointed by `&Context` do not alias, but it looks like there is not way to tell that to the compiler.

If I change `HWREGS` definition as this:

```
extern uint32_t * const restrict HWREGS;
```

that is, I hide the fixed memory address to the compiler, I get this:

```
example:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR HWREGS[rip]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax+18640], 5
        movabs  rax, 528280977531
        mov     QWORD PTR Context[rip], rax
        ret
Context:
        .zero   8
```

Now the two writes to Context are optimized (even coalesced to a single write), but on the other hand the access to the hardware register does not happen anymore with a direct memory access but it goes through a pointer indirection.

Is there a way to obtain optimal code here? I would like GCC to know that HWREGS is at a fixed memory address and at the same time to tell it that it does not alias `Context`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid compilers reloading regularly values from a memory region (possibly due to aliasing), then the best is not to use global variables, or at least *not to use direct accesses to global variables*. The `register` keyword seems ignored for global variables (especially here on `HWREGS`) for both GCC and Clang. Using the `restrict` keyword on function parameters solves this problem:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t * const HWREGS = 0x20000;

struct Context {
    uint32_t a, b;
} context;

static inline void exampleWithLocals(uint32_t* restrict localRegs, struct Context* restrict localContext) {
    localContext->a = 123;
    localRegs[0x1234] = 5;
    localContext->b = localContext->a;
}

void example() {
    exampleWithLocals(HWREGS, &context);
}
```

Here is the result (see also on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4aY81zTsc)):

```
example:
        movabs  rax, 528280977531
        mov     DWORD PTR ds:149712, 5
        mov     QWORD PTR context[rip], rax
        ret
context:
        .zero   8
```

Please note that the strict aliasing rule do not help in this case since the type of read/written variables/fields is always `uint32_t`.

Besides this, based on its name, the variable `HWREGS` looks like a hardware register. Please note that it should be put `volatile` so that compiler do not keep it to registers nor perform any similar optimization (like assuming the pointed value is left unchanged if the code do not change it).

Comment: Thanks! Any reason why it can't be made to work with global variables? Is it just because there's no way to specify "restrict" outside of the context of a function?

Comment: I suspect this is a limitation of the compilers and not the C standard but I am not sure. You can find the formal definition of the `restrict` keyword in the section 6.7.3.1 of the [C99 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). If find this section pretty hard to understand, but there is an example with global variables. Note particularly the rule 6 stating that *a translator is free to ignore any or all aliasing implications of uses of `restrict`*. In practice, global variables cause issues in many optimization steps of current mainstream compilers.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: The Standard allows the `restrict` qualifier on things other than automatic objects, but I don't think the authors gave much thought to corner cases.  The semantics of restrict-qualified pointers are tightly coupled to the lifetime of objects containing them, since accesses made via restrict-qualified pointers are unsequenced with regard to accesses made by other means *during the lifetime of the restrict-qualified pointer objects*, but they become nebulous for objects whose lifetime never ends.